# Downsides of using concrete (persisted) calculated property in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an entity called `Group` that has a navigation property `ICollection<User> Users`. In many cases when I get a group or groups I don't usually need to have all the users enumerated, but I would like to have their count.

I've noticed that the following code

`public int UsersCount() { return this.Users.Count(); }`

will persist *a* count to the database.

I am wondering if this is an abuse of a feature of Code-First, and if not, what the behavior of this is, ie:

1. Does it calculate the `UsersCount()` every time the `Group` is fetched?
2. If not, when *does* it recalculate and persist the value?

Comment: I would advise against this. There is a possiblity of EF persisting the wrong count to the database if you are not careful. I would advise instead you do the following `var userCounts = context.Groups.Select(x => new {x.Id, Count = x.Users.Count()} );`.

Comment: @Aron thanks, I figured it was not best practice. But can you explain how the wrong count could get saved?

Comment: Ah...I forgot, most people have Lazy loading enabled. In that case you might get away with it....

Comment: @Aron, yes I do have lazy loading enabled

Comment: Is this method wrapped in some property? I don't see how EF could save this count otherwise. Anyhow, I would never do this, because I hate redundancy (1) and because it is error prone (2).